# Flutter TextField not responding inside FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently stucked and confused with Flutter.

I have a FutureBuilder as below:

```
  Widget initView(double width) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchVehicles(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Vehicle>> snapShotData) {
          switch (snapShotData.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return loadingView();
            case ConnectionState.done:
              return TextField();
            default:
              return loadingView();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

And fetchVehicles() is as below:

```
Future<List<Vehicle>> fetchVehicles() async {
    List<Vehicle>vehicles = await APIService.fetchVehicles();
    return vehicles;
  }
```

When the future is invoked, the Loading indicator is shown and then when it is done the TextField is finally displayed.

Now, where my dilemma is right now is that the moment I tap into the TextField and wants to start typing the future starts re-executing thereby making the loader to be displayed again.

This has made it impossible for me to type into the TextField.

This is really frustrating. I never saw this coming.

Someone please help me. I'm confused because I don't see anything wrong in this code.

This is all I keep seeing in the log:

```
I/HwSecImmHelper( 3644): mSecurityInputMethodService is null
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3644): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3644): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3644): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3644): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3644): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3644): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 3644): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder

Your issue is related to this:

> If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

You call the future function to initState. Future function call only one time.

```
 Future<List<Vehicle>> futureVehicleList;
    @override
      void initState() {
       futureVehicleList=fetchVehicles();
        super.initState();
      }
    
    -----------
    
    Widget initView(double width) {
        return Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: futureVehicleList,
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. This worked. I'm still surprised why it does. I hate to say flutter sucks! Lolz. But, I have no choice, it's still unarguably the best framework out there considering its platform coverage.

Comment: FutureBuilder calls the future function again every time the 'build' function runs. Since the 'build' function reruns when the keyboard is opened, it is called again in the future function. The probable problem is solved by adding scaffold 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false', but this time the screen is not automatically arranged according to the keyboard when the keyboard is opened.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not on the Future Builder . The problem is in the textInputField .
if you use `onChanged` method in your TextInputField . Change this to `onFieldSubmitted`:

```
onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
             
            },
```

Your Inactive Problem Will be solved .